# Can I use BERT as a feature extractor without any finetuning on my specific data set?

Tags: pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to solve a multilabel classification task of 10 classes with a relatively balanced training set consists of ~25K samples and an evaluation set consists of ~5K samples.

I'm using the huggingface:

```
model = transformers.BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(...
```

and obtain quite nice results (ROC AUC = 0.98).

However, I'm witnessing some odd behavior which I don't seem to make sense of -

I add the following lines of code:

```
for param in model.bert.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
```

while making sure that the other layers of the model are learned, that is:

```
[param[0] for param in model.named_parameters() if param[1].requires_grad == True]
gives
['classifier.weight', 'classifier.bias']
```

Training the model when configured like so, yields some embarrassingly poor results (ROC AUC = 0.59).

I was working under the assumption that an out-of-the-box pre-trained BERT model (without any fine-tuning) should serve as a relatively good feature extractor for the classification layers. So, where do I got it wrong?

Comment: Can you please add directly to your question the output of: `[p[0] for p in model.named_parameters() if p[1].requires_grad == True]`?

Answer (score 3):

From my experience, you are going wrong in your assumption

> an out-of-the-box pre-trained BERT model (without any fine-tuning) should serve as a relatively good feature extractor for the classification layers.

I have noticed similar experiences when trying to use BERT's output layer as a word embedding value with little-to-no fine-tuning, which also gave very poor results; and this also makes sense, since you effectively have `768*num_classes` connections in the simplest form of output layer. Compared to the millions of parameters of BERT, this gives you an almost negligible amount of control over intense model complexity. However, I also want to cautiously point to overfitted results when training your full model, although I'm sure you are aware of that.

The entire idea of BERT is that it *is* very cheap to fine-tune your model, so to get ideal results, I would advise against freezing any of the layers. The one instance in which it can be helpful to disable at least partial layers would be the embedding component, depending on the model's vocabulary size (~30k for BERT-base).

Comment: Not sure if you agree, but personally I think that 0.59 is a decent result when you consider 10 classes and the short training time. @dennlinger

Comment: I can't really judge how good exactly it is, but compared to the near-perfect results with full fine-tuning, I'd still prefer the better results in the end ;-) I think we're also really blessed with general results of BERT overall, so it might make some otherwise decent results just "feel" worse...

Comment: Thank you so much for the support @dennlinger. I still find these results quite surprising but it's nice to know that it might actually be a valid behavior and not just some random bug... I guess that further benchmarking will raise my confidence in these results.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following will help in demystifying the odd behavior I reported here earlier –

First, as it turned out, when freezing the BERT layers (and using an out-of-the-box pre-trained BERT model without any fine-tuning), the number of training epochs required for the classification layer is far greater than that needed when allowing all layers to be learned.

For example,

**Without freezing the BERT layers**, I’ve reached:

```
ROC AUC = 0.98, train loss = 0.0988, validation loss = 0.0501 @ end of epoch 1

ROC AUC = 0.99, train loss = 0.0484, validation loss = 0.0433 @ end of epoch 2

Overfitting, train loss = 0.0270, validation loss = 0.0423 @ end of epoch 3
```

Whereas, **when freezing the BERT layers**, I’ve reached:

```
ROC AUC = 0.77, train loss = 0.2509, validation loss = 0.2491 @ end of epoch 10

ROC AUC = 0.89, train loss = 0.1743, validation loss = 0.1722 @ end of epoch 100

ROC AUC = 0.93, train loss = 0.1452, validation loss = 0.1363 @ end of epoch 1000
```

The (probable) conclusion that arises from these results is that working with an out-of-the-box pre-trained BERT model as a feature extractor (that is, freezing its layers) while learning only the classification layer suffers from ***under*fitting**.

This is demonstrated in two ways:

First, after running 1000 epochs, the model still hasn’t finished learning (the training loss is still higher than the validation loss).

Second, after running 1000 epochs, the loss values are still higher than the values achieved with the non-freeze version as early as the 1’st epoch.

To sum it up, @dennlinger, I think I completely agree with you on this:

> The entire idea of BERT is that it is very cheap to fine-tune your model, so to get ideal results, I would advise against freezing any of the layers.

Comment: Did you train the classifier only also with a small learning rate as the whole BERT? I suggest a proper increase :)

Comment: Good point. the answer is No. As opposed to the `lr~e-5` recommended for fine-tuning, here I used `lr~e-3`, which, as mentioned, did not help me escape the region of underfitting.

Comment: Not sure if you are still interested in it, but could you try 0.01 and also measure the training time?

Comment: I've tried 0.01 as you requested. The model is still underfitted after 100 epochs. The training time remained as before ~2sec per epoch. This indeed is very fast, however I'm training only a single 768*10 fully connected layer using two 1080 Ti machines as well as using the already-extracted pooler-outputs of 768 long vectors.